# Cannot load all assets on iphone 4

Tags: ios, performance, libgdx, robovm

I decided to start testing on iOS now that the Android version is closed to finished.
After my app has compiled and the splash screen is finished, I get this error. I am developing on a Mac (El capitan) using android studio. I'm using LibGdx and RoboVM and it seems an issue with RoboVM is causing this error.
There are no solutions online, please help.

```
[ERROR] AppLauncher failed with an exception:
[ERROR] org.robovm.libimobiledevice.LibIMobileDeviceException: IDEVICE_E_UNKNOWN_ERROR
[ERROR]     at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.IDevice.checkResult(IDevice.java:189)
[ERROR]     at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.IDeviceConnection.receive(IDeviceConnection.java:102)
[ERROR]     at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.receiveGdbPacket(AppLauncher.java:443)
[ERROR]     at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.receiveGdbPacket(AppLauncher.java:425)
[ERROR]     at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.pipeStdOut(AppLauncher.java:779)
[ERROR]     at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.launchInternal(AppLauncher.java:727)
[ERROR]     at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.launch(AppLauncher.java:1045)
[ERROR]     at org.robovm.compiler.target.ios.AppLauncherProcess$1.run(AppLauncherProcess.java:60
```

gdxVersion = '1.9.1'

roboVMVersion = '1.12.0'

EDIT:
It seems like this error is thrown when I load all my resources, If I just pick about 80% of my resources it loads fine (If I try to load all it makes it to about 96% then crashes, I use AssetManager). Is there some sort of size restriction on iOS devices? My asset folder is only 16.9MB.

EDIT 2:
Okay, So I am almost certain it's because I'm loading all my assets at launch, maybe it's too much for the ihpone4 GPU? It is pretty old now after all. Could this be the reason? I mean the error message I get makes no sense,  thought that type of error would give "out of memory"-message, but I'm really new to iOS so maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

It might be linked to IOS version on your iPhone 4. Did you try with a device that supports IOS 9?

Comment: No I dont have one yet unfortunately, #indie struggles. But I'm searching high and low to loan one